# Strategy to replace spaces in string

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store a string replacing its spaces with some character. When I retrieve it back I need to replace the character with spaces again. I have thought of this strategy while storing I will replace (space with _a) and (_a with _aa) and while retrieving will replace (_a with space) and (_aa with _a). i.e even if the user enters _a in the string it will be handled. But I dont think this is a good strategy. Please let me know if anyone has a better one?

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why do you need to replace spaces in a string?

Comment: what i want to know is what will happen if your original string contains _aa then how you will differentiate...

Comment: there's gotta be more to this. I just know it...

Comment: There are 66 code points that are guaranteed to never be used in Unicode data.  One possibility then, is to upgrade your data to UTF8 or UTF16, and then transcode your spaces to, say, 0xFDD0.  This is no good for interchange.  It's intended for internal use, but since we don't know what your real problem is, it's a suggestion that *might* work for you.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Non-character-code-points  (A Perl related document, but the info on non-character cp's is good).

Answer (score 2):

Replacing spaces with *something* is a problem when *something* is already in the string. Why don't you simply encode the string - there are many ways to do that, one is to convert all characters to hexadecimal.

For instance

```
  Hello world!
```

is encoded as

```
  48656c6c6f20776f726c6421
```

The space is 0x20. Then you simply decode back (hex to ascii) the string.
This way there are no space in the encoded string.

*-- **Edit** - optimization --*

You replace all `%` and all spaces in the string with `%xx` where `xx` is the hex code of the character.

For instance

```
   Wine having 12% alcohol
```

becomes

```
   Wine%20having%2012%25%20alcohol
```

- %20 is space
- %25 is the % character

This way, neither `%` nor  (space) are a problem anymore - Decoding is easy.

Encoding algorithm

```
   - replace all `%` with `%25`
   - replace all ` ` with `%20`
```

Decoding algorithm

```
   - replace all `%xx` with the character having `xx` as hex code
```

(You may even optimize more since you need to encode only two characters: use `%1` for `%` and `%2` for , but I recommend the `%xx` solution as it is more portable - and may be utilized later on if you need to code more characters)

Comment: That does solve the problem (although there are more efficient encodings---base64 or something similar).  On the other hand, it systematically doubles the size of the string, and makes reading it by a human somewhat problematic.  These may or may not be problems (since he doesn't say why he needs to remove the spaces), but might be points to consider.

Comment: What the edit proposes is URL escaped encoding.  Which has the advantage that you can probably find open source software to do it already written, and that it is totally extensible: you define a list of legal characters, and if the character isn't in the list, you replace it.  (Perhaps later he'll have to replace newlines, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your solution will work.  When reading, how would you
distinguish between strings that were orginally `" a"` and strings that
were originally `"_a"`: if I understand correctly, both will end up
`"_aa"`.

In general, given a situation were a specific set of characters cannot
appear as such, but must be encoded, the solution is to choose one of
allowed characters as an "escape" character, remove it from the set of
allowed characters, and encode all of the forbidden characters 
(including the escape character) as a two (or more) character sequence
starting with the escape character.  In C++, for example, a new line is
not allowed in a string or character literal.  The escape character is
`\`; because of that, it must be encoded as an escape sequence as well.
So we have `"\n"` for a new line (the choice of `n` is arbitrary), and
`"\\"` for a `\`.  (The choice of `\` for the second character is also
arbitrary, but it is fairly usual to use the escape character, escaped,
to represent itself.)  In your case, if you want to use `_` as the
escape character, and `"_a"` to represent a space, the logical choice
would be `"__"` to represent a `_` (but I'd suggest something a little
more visually suggestive—maybe `^` as the escape, with `"^_"` for
a space and `"^^"` for a `^`).  When reading, anytime you see the escape
character, the following character must be mapped (and if it isn't one
of the predefined mappings, the input text is in error).  This is simple
to implement, and very reliable; about the only disadvantage is that in
an extreme case, it can double the size of your string.

Comment: A minor modification makes this more efficient. For reading, map `^_` to <space>, `^^` to `^` and `^x` to `^x` (where `x` is neither `_` nor `^`). To encode, map <space> to `^_`; `^` if followed by `^` or `_` or <space> to `^^`; otherwise, leave the character as is. This just uses the illegal codings in your solution to reduce space consumption. If spaces are more common than `^`, then you can adjust to make `^x` decode as <space> `x`, making compensatory changes to the encoding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement this using C/C++? I think you should split your string into multiple part, separated by space.

If your string is like this : "a__b" (multiple space continuous), it will be splited into:

```
sub[0] = "a";
sub[1] = "";
sub[2] = "b";
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

With a normal string, using X characters, you cannot write or encode a string with x-1 using only 1 character/input character. 
You can use a combination of 2 chars to replace a given character (this is exactly what you are trying in your example).

To do this, loop through your string to count the appearances of a space combined with its length, make a new character array and replace these spaces with "//" this is just an example though. The problem with this approach is that you cannot have "//" in your input string.

Another approach would be to use a rarely used char, for example "^" to replace the spaces.

The last approach, popular in a combination of these two approaches. It is used in unix, and php to have syntax character as a literal in a string. If you want to have a " " ", you simply write it as \" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Replace function

```
String* stringWithoutSpace= stringWithSpace->Replace(S" ", S"replacementCharOrText");
```

So now stringWithoutSpace contains no spaces. When you want to put those spaces back,

```
String* stringWithSpacesBack= stringWithoutSpace ->Replace(S"replacementCharOrText", S" ");
```

Comment: As the original poster already noted, this will not work if `replacementCharOrText` already appears in the original string.

Comment: There is no such function in C++ (nor C).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there is more to this question than appears; for example, that you the strings you are storing must not only be free of spaces, but they must also look like words or some such. You should be clear about your requirements (and you might consider satisfying the curiosity of the spectators by explaining why you need to do such things.)

Edit: As JamesKanze points out in a comment, the following won't work in the case where you can have more than one consecutive space. But I'll leave it here anyway, for historical reference. (I modified it to compress consecutive spaces, so it at least produces unambiguous output.)

```
std::string out;
char prev = 0;
for (char ch : in) {
  if (ch == ' ') {
    if (prev != ' ') out.push_back('_');
  } else {
    if (prev == '_' && ch != '_') out.push_back('_');
    out.push_back(ch);
  }
  prev = ch;
}
if (prev == '_') out.push_back('_');
```

Comment: This won't work.  Consider the output of `"_"` and <two spaces> (sorry about the formatting, but I can't find any way of making a string with two spaces in this box---`&nbsp;` doesn't seem to work).

Comment: @JamesKanze: quite right. *What* was I thinking? I considered correcting it but I think just escaping every character is simpler and not too costly in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think just coding to ascii hexadecimal is a neat idea, but of course doubles the amount of storage needed.

If you want to do this using less memory, then you will need two-letter sequences, and have to be careful that you can go back easily.

You could e.g. replace blank by `_a`, but you also need to take care of your escape character `_`. To do this, replace every `_` by `__` (two underscores). You need to scan through the string once and do both replacements simultaneously.

This way, in the resulting text all original underscores will be doubled, and the only other occurence of an underscore will be in the combination `_a`. You can safely translate this back. Whenever you see an underscore, you need a lookahed of 1 and see what follows. If an `a` follows, then this was a blank before. If `_` follows, then it was an underscore before.

Note that the point is to replace your escape character (`_`) in the original string, and not the character sequence to which you map the blank. Your idea with replacing `_a` breaks. as you do not know if `_aa` was originally `_a` or `a` (blank followed by a).